# looking for a way to calculate logarithm in a DOS batch file

Tags: batch-file

Quick question. I've been looking desperately for a way calculate logarithm in a DOS batch data.Please help kindly.

Comment: cmd can't calculate with decimal numbers, eg. 3.1415692 :)

Answer (score 3):

the best way is making executable logarithm file and use it in your batch file, msdos have not any log function.. you can use some source code like this:
[http://en.literateprograms.org/Logarithm_Function_(Python)](http://en.literateprograms.org/Logarithm_Function_%28Python%29)

Comment: +1: I agree: the logarithm computation could be done in Python, Perl, Awk or some other scripting language that returns the result on standard output. For example, if you have `bc` available (e.g. from Cygwin), you could use `echo l(2) | bc -l` to return log(2).

Answer (score 1):

You may use this very simple Batch-JScript hybrid file:

```
@if (@CodeSection == @Batch) @then

@echo off

rem JSExpr.bat: Evaluate a JScript (aritmethic) expression
rem Antonio Perez Ayala

Cscript //nologo //E:JScript "%~F0" %1
goto :EOF

End of Batch section

@end

// JScript section

WScript.Echo(eval(WScript.Arguments.Unnamed.Item(0)));
```

For example:

```
C:>jsexpr Math.log(10)
2.30258509299405
```

As a matter of fact, you may evaluate *any* valid JScript arithmetic expression with previous program. For example:

```
C:>jsexpr Math.E
2.71828182845905
```

Search for "jscript reference" (math object), for example: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/b272f386(v=vs.94).aspx

Antonio

Answer (score 0):

There are several free command line calculators for DOS available.
For example [EVAL](http://tp.lc.ehu.es/anonym/msdos/eval100.zip).
It's well documented.

Or [Mathfc24](http://archives.scovetta.com/pub/simtelnet/msdos/calculte/mathfc24.zip)